# Tailwindcss animate blur

Tags: css, frontend, css-animations, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

How to do custom  animate by blur in tailwind

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      keyframes: {
        blur: {
          '0%': {filter: blur(2px)} ,
          '100%': {filter: blur(3px)},
        },
      },
      animation: {
        'blur': 'blur 2s linear ',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

That not work for me .

I want to make animation to my pop-up window with blur

Comment: Did it fix your problem? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must wrap your `blur(0px)` parameter with parenthesis (`"blur(0px)"`).
You can take a look at the examples provided on the [documentation page](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/animation#using-custom-values).

In tailwind, the keyframe's key needs to get a string as its value:

HTML:

```
<div class="bg-red-500 animate-blur"> ~ Blurry text ~ <div>
```

Config:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      keyframes: {
        blur: {
          '0%': { filter: "blur(0px)" },
          '100%': { filter: "blur(5px)" },
        }
      },
      animation: {
        blur: 'blur 2s linear infinite',
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/jOfLsBg1tr?file=config)